# Linked list infinite loop issue

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, hashtable

I am working on a hashtable and from each index of the hashtable the user is able to update a linked list from that index and create a list of friends for the person in that hashtable index. I am successfully adding names to the list but I can not seem to figure out how to print them. I continuously get an infinite loop that prints the first name in the list over and over.

```
void printFriends(char *name){
    struct node *myNode=searchForPerson(name); //returns address of node in the hash

    if(myNode->nxtfriend==NULL)
        printf("No Friends\n");

    while(myNode!=NULL){
        printf("%s ",myNode->value);
        myNode=myNode->nxtfriend;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

 void insertFriend(char *name,char *friend){
struct node *friendee=searchForPerson(name);
struct node *newfriend=createFriend(friend);

if(friendee->nxtfriend==NULL)
    friendee->nxtfriend=newfriend;

if(friendee->nxtfriend!=NULL){
    newfriend->nxtfriend=friendee->nxtfriend;
    friendee->nxtfriend=newfriend;
}
```

Comment: This code looks fine. I suspect the problem is in the code that creates the linked list, it's not setting the link in the last node to `NULL`.

Comment: If you're continuously seeing the same name, it must have set the link to point to itself instead of `NULL`.

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful.

Comment: I've added the create function

Comment: No you didn't...

Answer (score 1):

In `insertFriend`, you create a node that points back to itself.

First, the check for last node (`if(friendee->nxtfriend==NULL) friendee->nxtfriend=newfriend;`) will point `friendee->nxtfriend` to the new friend.  Then on the next statement, if `nxtfriend` is not NULL (which it isn't because you just set it to `nxtfriend`), you set `newFriend->nxtfriend` to `friendee->nxtfriend`, which you just set to `newFriend`.  This results in `newFriend->nxtfriend == newFriend`, and your infinite loop.

Reconsider how you want to insert nodes into your list.